# Questions about participations in run events

Tags: discussion, scope

Do questions considering participation in run events, eg. about how ITRA points are working, criteria for qualify, are on topic on Physical Fitness?

If no, are they on topic on other Stack Exchange, eg. Sports? The scope definition of Sports vs. Fitness is not quite clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would not be on topic on Fitness, as most of the questions we have are about how to improve your fitness. I believe this would be on topic on sports, as it is about the rules and points.